# Tkinter fill whole line with background colour

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm looking at this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm) for filling a Text widget with a background colour. However I want the background colour to appear for the entire line not just where there is text. So from the example I could just say:

```
text.tag_add("here", "1.0", "1.80")
text.tag_config("here", background="yellow", foreground="blue")
```

This is because a standard Text widget is 80 characters wide. This didn't work either did:

```
text.tag_add("here", "1.0", 1.END)
text.tag_config("here", background="yellow", foreground="blue")
```

These both had the same undesired effects. The effect I am trying to achieve is something similar to the iTunes list(see image) where each line alternates in colour. Is this going to be achieveable with the using the Text Element? I know that they are tables in with alternating rows being different colours however as I have simple strings that vary on another factor and thought it would be a good way to show the difference.

[image: Example of iTunes list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `line_number + 1`  `.`  `0` as `endindex`.

**UPDATE**

Specify `line_number` `.0+1lines` as `endindex`.
(See [The Tkinter Text Widget documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm), especially *Expressions* part)

Minimal example:

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *

text = Text()
text.pack()
text.insert(END, '1st\n2nd\n3rd')
# text.tag_add("here", "2.0", "3.0") # <----------------------
text.tag_add("here", "2.0", "2.0+1lines") # <----------------------
text.tag_config("here", background="yellow", foreground="blue")
mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I hadn't thought to increment the line number as I assumed that it would have also changed the background colour for that line.

Comment: @Dean, I found better way than manually adding 1. I updated the answer. Check it out.